# First step analysis in the context of hitting times

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

I've recently started reading through *Stochastic Calculus and Financial Applications* by J. Michael Steele and I'm not sure I understand how first step analysis works regarding hitting times. Exercise 1.1 of the book gives the following probability distribution for the up and down movements of a stock:

$$\mathbb{P}(Y_{n+1}=k+1|Y_n=k)=1/3\quad \mathrm{and}\quad \mathbb{P}(Y_{n+1}=k-1|Y_n=k)=2/3 \;\;\mathrm{for} \;k>20$$
$$\mathbb{P}(Y_{n+1}=k+1|Y_n=k)=2/3\quad \mathrm{and}\quad \mathbb{P}(Y_{n+1}=k-1|Y_n=k)=1/3 \;\;\mathrm{for} \;k<20$$
$$\mathbb{P}(Y_{n+1}=21|Y_n=20)=0.9\quad \mathrm{and}\quad \mathbb{P}(Y_{n+1}=19|Y_n=20)=0.1$$
The exercise asks for the expected value of the hitting time:
$$\tau = \min (n:Y_n=18|Y_0=25)$$
The answer in: [Finding the expected time for a stock to go from $\$25$ to $\$18$ given there is a support level at $20 with upward and downward biases.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656214/finding-the-expected-time-for-a-stock-to-go-from-25-to-18-given-there-is) suggests that we can partition the expected time into three distinct parts. They derive an answer for the 21->20 case, but I would like some clarification.

Suppose that $\tau_{1} = \min(n:Y_{n+1}<Y_n)$, then by applying the Law of Total Expectation, conditioning on the first step, we have
$$\mathbb{E}[\tau_{1}|Y_0=25]=\mathbb{P}(Y_1=26|Y_0=25)\cdot\mathbb{E}[\tau_{1}|Y_0=25,Y_1=26]+\mathbb{P}(Y_1=24|Y_0=25)\cdot\mathbb{E}[\tau_{1}|Y_0=25,Y_1=24]+1$$
The last '$+1$' accounts for the fact that we have 'moved forward' by adding the next $Y_1$ conditions. Then, applying the known probability distribution of $Y$, we have
$$\mathbb{E}[\tau_{1}|Y_0=25]=\frac 13\cdot\mathbb{E}[\tau_{1}|Y_0=25,Y_1=26]+\frac 23 \cdot\mathbb{E}[\tau_{1}|Y_0=25,Y_1=24]+1$$
I know that $\{Y_0=25,Y_1=24\} \Rightarrow \tau_1=1$, which means
$$\mathbb{E}[\tau_{1}|Y_0=25]=\frac 13\cdot\mathbb{E}[\tau_{1}|Y_0=25,Y_1=26]+\frac 23+1,$$
but this is where I get stuck. The book and the above answer imply that $$\mathbb{E}[\tau_{1}|Y_0=25,Y_1=26] = \mathbb{E}[\tau_1+1|Y_0=25].$$ Why exactly are we adding the '$+1$'? Is this true in general, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[\tau_{1}|Y_0=k,Y_1=k+1] = \mathbb{E}[\tau_1+1|Y_0=k]$? The book gives this rationale to a similar problem:

> When we take our first step, two things happen. First, there is the
> passage of one unit of time; and, second, we will have moved from zero to either
> -1 or 1.

Doesn't the first '$+1$' in the beginning application of the Law of Total Expectation account for this passage of time? I realise that this question may be a little trivial, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: $\tau_1$ is the first time we make a negative step. So long as we are above $21$ (which is true here), the probability of making a negative step is always $2/3$. If our first step is from $25$ to $26$, then *after* this move, our expected time to take a negative step is still $\tau_1$. We add $1$ because we have effectively "wasted" the first step.